# Why is WebView2 so slow to render a basic page with 1 line of text?

Tags: c#, .net, webview2

I am attempting to use WebView2 for showing some docs in my program, but it is soooo slow to render pages. (I'm not referring to the startup time of calling `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`. I am loading pages via the `WebResourceRequested` event. The dev tools show the page takes 10-12ms to download, but then it takes 2 seconds to actually render the page. It's just test pages made from the most basic html boilerplate with 1 line in the body, no other sources are needed for them. Is this normal?

So far this seems specific to intercepting the request via the `WebResourceRequested` event. Loading something like google.com is working much faster.

Comment: Try using `CefSharp`. They use the same backend (Chromium), so the API is similar (but not identical), but it tries to do less "smart" things (like not initializing when invisible) and it renders correctly in non-window situations (WPF, headless off-screen, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a bug in WebView2. Here is the post about it on their feedback repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2381

A workaround is to use a `file://` protocol instead of a `http(s)://`.